# Sheets record time vs PB time delta

Tags: google-sheets, time

I'm making a spreadsheet to track and compare PB times in a racing game to records in different regions. Trying to figure a way to show a + / - time differential comparing my time to the selected region's record time.

I found a way to make this work in Excel (using the SIGN formula and an if statement to combine the + or - to the calculated difference, required 2 extra columns which had to be hidden which wasnt ideal), but sheets doesn't agree with the format of my data (Tried with it being number, text, time and a custom mm:ss.000 format too).

Is there a way to do this in sheets and preferably a way that just requires the single cell to figure it out?
Thanks!

[image]

*Looking to have the time differences shown in the J column, comparing my PB time to the times adjacent times

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet with some dummy data and the expected output? It would be easier for the contributors here to troubleshoot.

Comment: Heres a sheet with the mock data and expected outputs https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ak4vAGC-oWrdRzI8FZv9Ho_UQKrU4POQY74pqDuv1VA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution, but you need to adjust your time format from `mm:ss.000` to `HH:mm:ss.000` to be able to subtract your time values. Then use [TEXT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139) to convert the results to your desired format

**Sample Formula: (Format: +/- s.000)**

```
=if($B$1-$B2>0,"+ ","- ")&text(abs($B$1-$B2),"s.000")
```

**Sample Formula: (Format: +/- mm:ss.000)**

```
=if($B$1-$B2>0,"+ ","- ")&text(abs($B$1-$B2),"mm:ss.000")
```

### Output:

[image]